How much infrastruture do I need for 10M users if I use WSO2 IS or Keycloak?
So my customer has a requirement where they want to implement SSO for a CIAM project. They have around 10M users and want to explore open-source tools for SSO(SAML/OIDC/OAuth).
So I need help to understand how much Infrastructure I need to put in the architecture if I want to implement either Keycloak or WSO2 IS.
I tried reading their blogs and official documentation but nothing gives a specific number as to how many concurrent requests are supported by default minimum installation infra.
Keycloak: Documentation
WSO2 IS: Documentation
